# How can I add a grid to an image using PHP and Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I would like to take a regular picture of a flower
and convert it to something similar to the following image:

[image]

The following code works great using ImageMagick (IM).
However, I want to be able to do this same thing using PHP 
and Imagick on a website.

```
convert ^
  in.png ^
  -background White ^
  -crop 0x6 -splice 0x6 -append -chop 0x6 ^
  -crop 6x0 -splice 6x0 +append -chop 6x0 ^
  out.png
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the image blocky or just add grid lines? If the former, then Use scaleImage to make the image smaller, then use scaleImage to make the image larger. If the latter, then create a grid of blocks of black and one row/column of white. Then tile that out and copy it to the alpha channel of itself. Then overlay that onto your image.

Comment: For PHP Imagick, you should just look up the same commands from https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=imagemagick. They would have similar names. This forum is not to tell you how, but to correct any mistakes you make in code you present. So you need to try yourself first.

Comment: While maybe not the most efficient code, I figured out a grid can be recreated by splicing the image up into little pieces, and then placing a border around each individual piece and then adding all the pieces together again. For example, the following code will divide an image (100 pixels in width x 200 pixels in height) into a grid of two and place borders in various colors around the top, left, bottom, right, and center.  See code above.

Comment: `$canvas = new Imagick();
  $canvas->newImage(200, 5, "green");   // Top border
  
  $stack = new Imagick();
  $stack->newImage(5, 100, "orange");  // Left Border

  $newClone = clone $image;
  $newClone->cropImage(100, 100, 1, 1); 
  $stack->addImage ($newClone);
  $stack->newImage(5, 100, "blue");    // Middle Border`

Comment: `$newClone = clone $image;`
`$newClone->cropImage(100, 100, 100, 1);`
`$stack->addImage ($newClone);`
 `$stack->newImage(5, 100, "purple");   // Right border`

  `$stack->resetIterator();`
  `$rowImage = $stack->appendImages(FALSE);`
  `$canvas->addImage($rowImage);`

  `$canvas->newImage(200, 5, "red");  // Bottom border`
  `$canvas->resetIterator();`
  `$combined = $canvas->appendImages(TRUE);`
  `$combined->setImageFormat("png"); `